# Why this Hello World exe flagged as malicious on Virustotal?

Tags: antivirus

I am compiling the following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello World!");
}
```

As you can see, it's just a normal program that print out `Hello World!` to console, there is no way this can harm your computer :)

I compiled it using `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` on Linux host with the version:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 10-win32 20210110
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But when I compile it with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc test.c -Ofast -o hello.exe` (you can get the binary [here](https://paste.c-net.org/SweetStadium), I uploaded it to paste.c-net.org), then upload it to Virustotal, it got [3/68 detections](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/1ba4feaf34aec01c649c2ac0ac2c06e6007d7e034564949edc277b5d90b43380/detection):

[image: detections]

Compiling with default optimize level (without `-Ofast`) `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc hello.c -o hello1.exe` (you can get the binary [here](https://paste.c-net.org/AirheadCravings)) results in [a lot more detections](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5e145056fee81b40bfc597b5d3abcf4c9af1c6e7fe6b1ea0e5f7e8d8796be255?nocache=1):

[image: detections]

How on Earth is that possible?

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423479/is-microsoft-using-a-tcp-connection-in-a-simple-c-program/72424835#72424835). In many cases the reports of Virustotal are misleading.

Comment: It's flagged as malicious, because, as you can see, it is making connections to IPs and creating files. The linked report above explains the effect.

Comment: @mentallurg we are getting quite a few of this same question the past couple of weeks. The dupe I linked to includes a fix. Should we create an answer to that dupe or make a canonical to point all these questions to?

Comment: @schroeder: Yes, it is a good idea.